# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.Pau.ImapNotes.Miscs.OneNote

Tags: java, android, casting

I'm trying to use the following piece of code from github.
I need some help as I'm not java expert.

in Listactivity.java:

```
Intent toDetail = new Intent(widget.getContext(), NoteDetailActivity.class);
toDetail.putExtra("selectedNote", (OneNote)noteList.get(selectedNote));
startActivity(toDetail);
```

in OneNote.java:

```
public class OneNote extends HashMap<String,String>{
[...]
        public OneNote(){
                super();
                this.put("title", "No Title");
                this.put("body", "No Body");
                this.put("date", "No Date");
        }

        public OneNote(String title, String body, String date){
                super();
                this.put("title", title);
                this.put("body", body);
                this.put("date", date);

        }
[...]
```

in NoteDetailActivity.java:

```
this.currentNote = (OneNote)getIntent().getExtras().get("selectedNote");
```

At run time I have the message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 8212): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.Pau.ImapNotes.Miscs.OneNote
E/AndroidRuntime( 8212):        at com.Pau.ImapNotes.NoteDetailActivity.onCreate(NoteDetailActivity.java:21)
```

Line 21 is the line above

Comment: it is better use `Parcelable` or `Serializable` to for sending object to another activity.

Comment: That's what he is doing.  HashMap is Serializable which in turn means so is OneNote.

Comment: you may be missing parenthesis in your cast. I'm assuming noteList is a HashMap of OneNotes? If that's the case the issue is probably because you're casting (OneNote)(noteList) instead of (OneNote)(noteList.get(selectedNote));

Comment: Just tried with parenthesis as Xiaoyu asked, but it's the same.

Comment: If I print (OneNote)noteList.get(selectedNote), content seem correct. In NoteDetailActivity (getIntent().getExtras().get("selectedNote")).getClass().getName() says it's HashMap

Comment: you should check that you imported the right OneNote from your package; or you could post more info on your package structure

Comment: Yes Kescha, it's the good one.

Comment: Listactivity.java and NoteDetailActivity.java are in ImapNotes dir  OneNote.java is in ImapNotes/Miscs. Paths are correct when importing

Comment: Please try a different approach. Break the line in note detail activity in 4 lines with correct casting for  every line

Comment: @KeschaSkywalker: that's what I did. I leaved putExtra as is. Changed the getExtra to : this.hm = (HashMap)getIntent().getExtras().get("selectedNote");  currentNote=new OneNote(this.hm.get("title").toString(),this.hm.get("body").toString(),this.hm.get("date").toString());  and it worked. But I'm not sure it's the best way to do that.  The main question is why HashMap cannot be cast to OneNote.  Thanks for your help. I'll vote for this solution.

Comment: Months later, I must add a comment. Even if KeschaSkywalker solved my problem, best solution to handle objects is Rustam's solution. Parcelable is a nice way to do that. During these months I have learned more and more things, leading me to write again. The problem for a beginner is that when just saying "use Parcelable", it's hard to understand what to do. Hope thie will help others.